# Experience cloud guest user Account access error

Tags: guest-user, experience-cloud

i've created a custom lightning component with a lookup field to the Account.
The lookup works fine with my Sys Admin user, however with the guest user profile it does not work, seems like that profile does not have access to the Account object.

The community is public.
I've already gave access to Account to that profile (read, write, all fields and record types)
Ive already changes the Sharing settings to external access for Accounts and Contracts to Public read/write

Comment: Are you accessing via Apex or some other way?  If it's Apex, make sure the profile has access to that class.

Comment: yes its from APEX, the class is without sharing. I also tried to check the available profiles for that class security and the Community profile is not one of the options. I added them all there and yet no luck

Comment: Take a look at https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/Guest-User-Record-Access-Development-Best-Practices , it probably has the answer to your question.

Comment: yes ive also created that sharing rule
the thing is actually deeper, it cannot only access the Account records, Im trying to access the object describe methods (Schema.describeSobjectresult) and its returning null

Comment: I think Victor's comment was a good one, since all the returns from APEX calls are returning null, it appears that the community profile does not have access to the class. However, how can I give this permission since the profile is not show on the APEX class security profile list?

Answer (score 0):

after writing my last comment I was able to find the solution which was actually the permission to the class (Victor's comment). However since the profile was not on the class list, I had to go to the profile and click on the top button: Enabled Apex Classes